# CLI bin executable node with package.json link

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I'm currently having troubles trying to execute the CLI of my lib inside the same folder.

I'm developing my own library that it has a CLI command, and I just added in the package.json as:

```
"bin": "cli/builder.js"
```

I have a folder `examples` inside my library repo, and one of these examples is using the CLI command.

Each `example` folder have their `package.json` with:

```
"dependencies": {
    "my-lib": "link:../../"
}
```

When I run `yarn install` on the example folder, the package of my library is added on `node_modules` and I can use my lib on the example project. However the `node_modules/.bin` doesn't have the bin map... Thus I can't run the CLI of my lib inside my examples.

Any idea?

Thanks you!

Comment: Just the typo, yes thanks, Im going to fix It on the message